# vscode cmake build terminal output color

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

Is it possible to influence the colors of certain output lines?

I would like to see the line 100% Built target of my project in green too.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some information relevant to how to reproduce the screenshot? What generator is this? (GNU Makefiles?) What CMake version are you using?